# only first column is echoed instead all of them

Tags: php

what is wrong here:

```
$itemsa = "date, name, phone, address, color, height";

function users($id) {
    global $db;
    global $_POST;
    global $itemsa;
    $sql = "select *  from users where id = :aid limit 1";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st -> execute([":aid" => $id]);
    $arra = explode(', ', $itemsa);
    $items = "";
    $x = 0;
    while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
        $items .=
        "<div class='rtitle' data-id = " . $row['id'] . ">" . mb_strtoupper($arra[$x]) . "</div>\n" .
        "<div class='rstory' data-id = " . $row['id'] . ">" . $row[$x] . "</div>\n";
        $x++;
    }
    echo $items;
}
```

Result:

```
<div class='rtitle' data-id = 3>DATE</div>
<div class='rstory' data-id = 3>21-09-2018 00:16</div>
```

So only first column is echoed, I expected 6 i.e. all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looping on the array of column names you pass to the function and not the fetch results as you only return ONE ROW from the query and you are interested in the columns returned in that one row.

You should also pass all those globals (except $_POST which is a global anyway and you dont appear to use in the function anyway) as parameters to you function call.

```
function users($db, $id, $itemsa) {

    $sql = "select *  from users where id = :aid limit 1";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st -> execute([":aid" => $id]);

    // you only have one row returned, so a simple fetch
    $row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $arra = explode(', ', $itemsa);
    $items = "";

    foreach ($itemsa as $col )  {
        $items .=
        "<div class='rtitle' data-id = " . $row['id'] . ">" . mb_strtoupper($row[$col]) . "</div>\n" .
        "<div class='rstory' data-id = " . $row['id'] . ">" . $row[$col] . "</div>\n";

    }
    echo $items;
}

$itemsa = "date, name, phone, address, color, height";

users($db, $id, $itemsa);
```

Comment: finally - I agree. You could make this earlier. thanks.